# Error: too much recursion jquery drupal

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drupal

i used drupal 6.26 and jquery_update jquery 1.7 min.js
when i used in custom my module

```
 $drupal_add_css('sites/all/libraries/jqgrid/themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css');
  drupal_add_js('sites/all/libraries/jqgrid/js/jquery.js');
  drupal_add_js('sites/all/libraries/jqgrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-fa.js');
  drupal_add_js('sites/all/libraries/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js');
  drupal_add_js('sites/all/libraries/jqgrid/js/jquery-ui-custom.min.js');
```

show this error
Error: too much recursion
Source File: sites/all/libraries/jqgrid/js/jquery-ui-custom.min.js?G
Line: 588

line : 588

```
$f.fn.extend({_addClass:f.fn.addClass,addClass:function(c,a,b,d){return a?f.effects.animateClass.apply(this,[{add:c},a,b,d]):this._addClass(c)},_removeClass:f.fn.removeClass,removeClass:function(c,a,b,d){return a?f.effects.animateClass.apply(this,[{remove:c},a,b,d]):this._removeClass(c)},_toggleClass:f.fn.toggleClass,toggleClass:function(c,a,b,d,e){return typeof a=="boolean"||a===j?b?f.effects.animateClass.apply(this,[a?{add:c}:{remove:c},b,d,e]):this._toggleClass(c,a):f.effects.animateClass.apply(this,
```

another question 
i used jquery update module .
drupal added jquery.js in all pages
when i used in my module it is working correctly

```
$drupal_add_css('sites/all/libraries/jqgrid/themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css');
  drupal_add_js('sites/all/libraries/jqgrid/js/jquery.js');
  drupal_add_js('sites/all/libraries/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqChart.min.js');
  drupal_add_js('sites/all/libraries/jqgrid/js/jquery-ui-custom.min.js');
```

but when i deleted

```
$drupal_add_js('sites/all/libraries/jqgrid/js/jquery.js');
```

my module not working

please guide me 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery UI](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_ui) and [jQuery Update](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) modules.
Maximum supported version of jQuery UI is 1.7.3 in Drupal 6.x so you will have to adjust your code with it.
Instead of adding external or other jquery.js, add it using the jQuery Update module.

Comment: please check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692256/jqgrid-jquery-drupal-6